# How to fetch only columns that satisfy the condition in one-to-many relationship in QueryDSL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, querydsl

I have two following entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "affiliate_programs")
@SequenceGenerator(name = AbstractEntity.GENERATOR, sequenceName = "affiliate_programs_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class AffiliateProgram extends AbstractAuditableDeletableEntity {

    private static final int DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 512;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "affiliateProgram", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<AffiliateProgramStatistics> statistics;

    public enum SortType implements ISortType {
        ID(QAffiliateProgram.affiliateProgram.id),
        TITLE(QAffiliateProgram.affiliateProgram.title),

        @Getter
        private ComparableExpressionBase[] expressions;

        SortType(final ComparableExpressionBase... expressions) {
            this.expressions = expressions;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "affiliate_programs_statistics")
@SequenceGenerator(name = AbstractEntity.GENERATOR, sequenceName = "affiliate_programs_statistics_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class AffiliateProgramStatistics extends AbstractAuditableEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AffiliateProgram affiliateProgram;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EventType eventType;

    private LocalDate date;

    public enum EventType {
        MERCHANTS,
        PRIORITY_MERCHANTS,
        COUPONS,
        CLICKS
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch only the columns from `AffiliateProgramStatistics` that match the SQL between condition. My SQL query looks like this:

```
select *
from affiliate_programs ap
         left join affiliate_programs_statistics aps on ap.id = aps.affiliate_program_id
where ap.deleted = false and aps.date between '2020-07-20' and '2020-08-20';
```

And the result of this query is exactly what I need - I get only columns that are NOT marked as deleted AND columns with date BETWEEN required dates.

I tried to write that query in QueryDSL and that's what I came up with:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AffiliateProgramsCustomRepositoryImpl implements AffiliateProgramsCustomRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Page<AffiliateProgram> search(final AffiliateProgramSearchForm form) {
        final QAffiliateProgram affiliateProgram = QAffiliateProgram.affiliateProgram;
        final QAffiliateProgramStatistics affiliateProgramStatistics = QAffiliateProgramStatistics.affiliateProgramStatistics;
        final JPAQuery<AffiliateProgram> query = new JPAQuery<AffiliateProgram>(entityManager)
                .distinct()
                .from(affiliateProgram)
                .leftJoin(affiliateProgram.statistics, affiliateProgramStatistics)
                .where(AffiliateProgramsRepositoryHelper.getPredicates(form))
                .orderBy(AffiliateProgramsRepositoryHelper.getOrders(form.getSorting()))
                .limit(form.getLimit())
                .offset(form.getOffset());

        return AffiliateProgramsRepositoryHelper.pageBy(query, form);
    }
}
```

```
public class AffiliateProgramsRepositoryHelper extends RepositoryHelper {

    public static Predicate[] getPredicates(final AffiliateProgramSearchForm form) {
        final QAffiliateProgramStatistics affiliateProgramStatistics = QAffiliateProgramStatistics.affiliateProgramStatistics;
        final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        final String formattedQuery = form.getFormattedQuery();

        if (!isNullOrEmpty(formattedQuery)) {
            predicates.add(affiliateProgramStatistics.affiliateProgram.title.likeIgnoreCase(formattedQuery));
        }

        predicates.add(affiliateProgramStatistics.date.between(form.getFrom(), form.getTo()));
        predicates.add(affiliateProgramStatistics.affiliateProgram.deleted.isFalse());

        return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]);
    }
}
```

But the result of this is not satisfying. If at least one of the columns in `AffiliateProgramStatistics` match the `between()` condition, it fetches every single column from the table that matches tje `leftJoin()` condition.

How can I fetch only the columns that I need?

P.S. Hibernate generates the following query:

```
Hibernate: 
select distinct 
  affiliatep0_.id as id1_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.created_date_time as created_2_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.last_modified_date_time as last_mod3_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.deleted as deleted4_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.clicks_count as clicks_c5_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.coupons_count as coupons_6_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.description as descript7_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.merchants_count as merchant8_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.priority_merchants_count as priority9_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.priority_order as priorit10_0_, 
  affiliatep0_.title as title11_0_ 
from affiliate_programs affiliatep0_ 
  inner join affiliate_programs_statistics statistics1_ on affiliatep0_.id=statistics1_.affiliate_program_id 
  cross join affiliate_programs affiliatep2_ 
  where statistics1_.affiliate_program_id=affiliatep2_.id 
    and (statistics1_.date between ? and ?) 
    and affiliatep2_.deleted=? 
  order by affiliatep0_.title desc nulls last limit ?
```

which works perfectly and fetches only the data I need if i run it in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA supports the ON clause in JPQL since 2.1, and QueryDSL is able to generate that ON clause in queries. Hibernate had a precedessor for the ON clause in the form of the now deprecated WITH clause. The ON clause can be used in more occasions.

Just use `.on(Predicate)` immediately after the join on which it should be applied:

```
    final JPAQuery<AffiliateProgram> query = new JPAQuery<AffiliateProgram>(entityManager)
            .distinct()
            .from(affiliateProgram)
            .leftJoin(affiliateProgram.statistics, affiliateProgramStatistics)
            .on(AffiliateProgramsRepositoryHelper.getPredicates(form))
            .orderBy(AffiliateProgramsRepositoryHelper.getOrders(form.getSorting()))
            .limit(form.getLimit())
            .offset(form.getOffset());
```